# promise then is not the function error for Node Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am using  `async/await` to return the `Promise` , to use it as promoise in node script. When I am trying to make use of the return value as `Promise` , its giving a error `a.then is not a function`

here is the sample code

```
function test () {

        //do something .......
        //....
        return global.Promise;

}

(async ()=> {

    let a = await test();
    a.then(()=> { console.log('good ')}, (err)=> { console.log()}); 
})();
```

Comment: You can use `return Promise.resolve( );`, but you will need to remove `await` as well for `a` to be the promise.

Answer (score 2):

The Promise constructor function isn't a promise, it is a tool to make promises with.

Even if it was a promise, since you are `await`ing the return value of `test`, it would have been resolved into a value before you try to call `then` on it. (The point of `await` is that it *replaces* the use of `then()` callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

You can await a function that returns a promise like this:

```
function test() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true) {
      reject("Custom error message");
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(56)
    }, 200);
  })
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const a = await test();
    console.log(a)
  } catch (e) { // this handles the "reject"
    console.log(e);
  }
}

main();
```

If you change the `true` to `false` you can test the "resolve" case.

Answer (score 0):

`await` retrieves the resolved value from a `Promise`

```
let a = await test(); // `a` is no longer a Promise
```

---

I've put together two ways of retrieving values from a `Promise`

**using await**

```
(async () => {
    try {
        let a = await test();
        console.log('Good', a);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

**using .then()**

```
test().then(a => {
    console.log('Good', a);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);        
});
```

Please note that, the `async` arrow function is removed because there is no `await` needed.